# Algorithm analysis, which one is correct?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm a programmer, but I've not learned CS, so I've poor understanding of algorithms analysis. I'm reading a book about this theme and I have a question:

Suppose we have a problem: Given two strings, we need to understand is the first string an anagram of the second string.

The first solution that I though was:

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    for char in s1:
        if not char in s2:
            return False
    return True
```

In analysis of such an algorithm, should I care about complexity of this piece of code?

```
if not char in s2
```

To be more precise is it important, which algorithm is used in search operation, which will be executed in each iteration of the for loop?

---

Ps: sorry for misunderstanding, I know that the algorithm is wrong, because an anagram strings should be the same length. But it is not important for now.

Comment: That is **not** a solution - containing the same set of letters does not guarantee that `s1` and `s2` anagrams (although not containing the same set does guarantee they aren't). Are `'ababa'` and `'ab'` anagrams? Are `'ababa'` and `'babab'`? And `not char in s2` will be `O(len(s2))`.

Comment: This algorithm returns true for `'a','ab'` (and `a` is certainly not an anagram of `ab`). You should worry about correctness before worrying about complexity.

Comment: Others have pointed out that your solution is not an actual solution. On top of that, it is O(n*m) in complexity, and given that your strings mostly are of equal size, that means you're quadratic. To avoid that, consider using a s2set = set(s2) instead. This will reduce the lookup from O(n) to O(1)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? If you're analysing the complexity of an algorithm, *of course* you should care about the complexity of each step.

Comment: @deets That is what I was looking for. So, in essence this code looks like O(n), but because search operation (for eg linear search) complexity is O(m), the total running time will be O(n*m)?

Comment: `char in s2` is `O(n)` if its a string or a list and `O(1)` if it is a set or a dictionary ...

Comment: @deets Converting the strings to sets before comparison will lead to false positives - "aab" is not an anagram of "abb", despite sets formed from the strings being identical, and the length being identical. Using multisets might mitigate that, but at that point, you might as well just sort the two strings character-by-character (`O(n log n)`) and then do a string comparison, which I think is about the best you can do...

Comment: @twalberg I know. That's why I said "Others have pointed out your solution isn't an actual solution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you analyse the complexity of each line (`n, m = len(s1), len(s2)` and I will assume `n > m`):

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    for char in s1: # O(n)
        if not char in s2: # O(m)
            return False # O(1)
    return True # O(1)
```

Note that `if not char in s2:` is `O(m)` as, in the worst case, you have to check every character in `s2` to be sure `char` isn't there.

Then you combine; as you have nested operations, the overall complexity is `O(n * m)`.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you can significantly improve by noting that membership testing for a `set` is `O(1)` (except where every hash collides, see e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    s2 = set(s2) # O(m)
    for char in s1: # O(n)
        if not char in s2: # O(1)
            return False # O(1)
    return True # O(1)
```

By moving the `O(m)` operation out of the loop, you reduce the overall complexity to `O(n)`.

**However, this algorithm does not actually determine whether `s1` and `s2` are anagrams.**

---

If you are looking for an efficient way to actually solve the problem, note that Python's sort (*"Timsort"*) is `O(n log n)`:

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    s1 = sorted(s1) # O(n log n)
    s2 = sorted(s2) # O(m log m)
    return s1 == s2 # O(m)
```

Now you have no nesting, so the total complexity is `O(n log n)`. This is admittedly slower than `O(n)`, but it has the advantage of working.

Comment: Man, this is AWESOME, thank you very much. This answer totally covers my question.

Comment: Your last example is nice, but the others are not working correctly, for example try `anagram("a", "ab")` which will return `True`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, i must have skipped that line.

Answer (score 1):

It just depends what you are analyzing the code for.

If your question is "how many times is an 'in' search performed", then you needn't worry about what 'in' does.

If your question is about the running time of the global algorithm, then yes you have to worry about the running time of 'in'.

This is why when you use the C++ STL containers, you should read about the time complexity in the manual. Unfortunately, as far as I know, this information is not available for Python.